# Is it possible to retrieve Ethereum sent to the unintended address?

Tags: erc-20, coinbase

I assumed that my UBX wallet is an Ethereum wallet since the coins in it are UBX coins that I sent to it from Kucoin, and Kucoin's UBX coins are ERC-20 coins. Hence, I sent some Ethereum to it so that I can trade the Ethereum for UBSN.

However, I later learned that my assumption was wrong; I overlooked that my UBX wallet's address begins with "Ux"rather than "0x."

Hence, after I pasted my UBX wallet's address into the recipient box on Coinbase, the coins were sent to an Ethereum address that's identical to my UBX address apart from beginning with "0x" rather than "Ux."

According to Etherscan, the Ethereum address has only one transaction in its history, which is the transaction via which I sent my Ethereum to it.

Is there any way that I can recover the Ethereum.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ethereum transaction cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Is there any way that I can determine the keys to the address, such as what was done in this article? https://medium.com/bitclave/how-we-sent-eth-to-the-wrong-address-and-successfully-recovered-them-2fc18e09d8f6

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have no idea what is UBX, but it doesn't make much difference here.

If you send assets to the right address but in the wrong network, there is a possibility that they can be recovered. This depends on two things:

1. Does the other network use the same logic for generating private and public keys as Ethereum
2. Is the one holding the private key for the address in the other network willing to help you (that might be yourself also)

Since the transaction was accepted, the logic of generating keys is probably the same (except changing the prefix). Therefore, someone probably holds the private key which could unlock the wallet in the network you used accidentally. So, at least in theory, that person has to use the same private key on Ethereum network, and the assets can be unlocked.

Comment: 1. The address is not owned by anyone; it was created by the transaction, which is evident by its lack of transaction history apart from the transaction via which I sent my Ethereum. 

2. The address is not a UBX address; it's an Ethereum address that has the same characters as my UBX address but begins with "Ux" rather than "0x." 

3. I've read that the sender of a transaction that creates an Ethereum address can use the private keys of their own address to access the created-recipient address.